# Having issue with Install-Module command

Tags: module, vmware

I am going to import the VMware module the Powershell, once I run this command "Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI -Scope CurrentUser" , I will get this error message: the term Install-Module is not recognized as the name of CMDlet, Function, Script file...
Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using this command

```
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -SkipPublisherCheck -AllowClobber
```